# getting table row of $this parent siblings table !

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a href link under my table and i want to be able to manipulate table rows by clicking on that link but i cant get them !

here is my html

```
<div>
  <div>  <a href="#remove" class="removelink" > remove </a> </div>

    <table>
    <tr> <td></td> </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

i want to do something like:

```
$('.removelink').click(function(){
$(this).parent().siblings('table tr:last').remove();
})
```

i can get to the table by

```
$(this).parent().siblings('table')
```

but i cant get rows by something like

```
$(this).parent().siblings('table tr')
```

Comment: Your Jquery code works fine . See the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yd49H/

Comment: @NullPointer: This removes the whole table for some reason.

Comment: @Felix.Thanks ..I didnt noticed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get to the `tr` from the `table`:

```
$('.removelink').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('table').find('tr:last').remove();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CDp8t/8/). If your HTML structure is always exactly as you've shown, you could use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead of `siblings('table')` for slightly shorter code.

The problem with your current code is that `siblings('table tr')` will look for a sibling of the `div` which is a `tr`, and there are none!

Answer (score 1):

`.siblings(selector)` will return all siblings of a certain element which match the selector.

`.siblings('table tr')` will only return something if the context element has `tr` elements as siblings but the `div` does not.

Just use `.find`:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('table').find('tr').last()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $context = $(this).parent().siblings('table');
$("tr:last", $context);
```