# Pseudo-selectors with siblings method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Earlier, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818024/getting-table-row-of-this-parent-siblings-table/), which was basically about removing a table row. This question came about as the result of the comments on that question. Given the following HTML:

```
<div><a href="#" class="removelink">remove</a></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('.removelink').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('table tr:last').remove();
});
```

I would expect nothing to happen, because the [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method should select the siblings of the currently matched element, optionally filtered by a selector. From the jQuery docs:

> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the
>   elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it.

Based on that, I read the above code as "get the siblings of the current element (the `div`) which are the last `tr` within a `table`". Obviously there are no elements that match that description - there is a `tr` within a `table`, but it's not a sibling of the `div`. So, I wouldn't expect any elements to be returned. However, it actually returns the entire table, as if it ignores the `tr:last` part of the selector entirely.

What confused me further was that if you remove the `:last` pseudo-selector, it works as expected (returning no elements).

Why is the entire table removed by the above code? Am I just being stupid and missing something obvious? You can see the above code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd49H/4/).

**Edit** - Here's a simplified version. Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="d1"></div>
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Why does the following jQuery return the second `div`:

```
$("#d1").siblings("div span:last");
```

I would expect it to return nothing, as there is not a `span` which is a sibling of `#d1`. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd49H/9/) for this simplified example.

**Update**

Following the brilliant investigation from @muistooshort, I have created a [jQuery bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10562) to track this issue.

Comment: but .. by the parent method you go up one level with your selection .. not ?

Comment: The `parent` method takes you from the `a` to the `div`.

Comment: Seems to have something to do with how jQuery interacts with Sizzle. `div span` and `div span:nth-child(1)` behave *sensible* in your second fiddle but `div span:first` and `div span:eq(0)` do not; the first two selectors are matched using the browser's native API, the second two are handled by Sizzle in JavaScript.

Comment: Now that jQuery 1.7 is available on jsfiddle.net, here's an updated fiddle which shows that the bug has indeed been fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd49H/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to expand on my comment a little bit. All of this is based on your second simplified example and jQuery 1.6.4. This is a little long winded perhaps but we need to walk through the jQuery code to find out what it is doing.

---

We do have the jQuery source available so let us go a wandering
through it and see what wonders there are to behold therein.

The guts of `siblings` looks like this:

```
siblings: function( elem ) {
    return jQuery.sibling( elem.parentNode.firstChild, elem );
}
```

wrapped up in this:

```
// `name` is "siblings", `fn` is the function above.
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( until, selector ) {
    var ret = jQuery.map( this, fn, until )

    //...

    if ( selector && typeof selector === "string" ) {
        ret = jQuery.filter( selector, ret );
    }

    //...
};
```

And then `jQuery.sibling` is this:

```
sibling: function( n, elem ) {
    var r = [];

    for ( ; n; n = n.nextSibling ) {
        if ( n.nodeType === 1 && n !== elem ) {
            r.push( n );
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

So we go up one step in the DOM, go to the parent's first child,
and continue sideways to get all of the parent's children (except
the node we started at!) as an array of DOM elements.

That leaves us with all of our sibling DOM elements in `ret` and
now to look at the filtering:

```
ret = jQuery.filter( selector, ret );
```

So what is `filter` all about? `filter` is all about this:

```
filter: function( expr, elems, not ) {
    //...
    return elems.length === 1 ?
        jQuery.find.matchesSelector(elems[0], expr) ? [ elems[0] ] : [] :
        jQuery.find.matches(expr, elems);
}
```

In your case, `elems` will have have exactly one element (as `#d1`
has one sibling) so we're off to `jQuery.find.matchesSelector` which
is actually `Sizzle.matchesSelector`:

```
var html = document.documentElement,
    matches = html.matchesSelector || html.mozMatchesSelector || html.webkitMatchesSelector || html.msMatchesSelector;
//...
Sizzle.matchesSelector = function( node, expr ) {
    // Make sure that attribute selectors are quoted
    expr = expr.replace(/\=\s*([^'"\]]*)\s*\]/g, "='$1']");

    if ( !Sizzle.isXML( node ) ) {
        try {
            if ( pseudoWorks || !Expr.match.PSEUDO.test( expr ) && !/!=/.test( expr ) ) {
                var ret = matches.call( node, expr );

                // IE 9's matchesSelector returns false on disconnected nodes
                if ( ret || !disconnectedMatch ||
                        // As well, disconnected nodes are said to be in a document
                        // fragment in IE 9, so check for that
                        node.document && node.document.nodeType !== 11 ) {
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    return Sizzle(expr, null, null, [node]).length > 0;
};
```

A bit of experimentation indicates that neither the Gecko nor WebKit
versions of `matchesSelector` can handle `div span:first` so we end
up in the final `Sizzle()` call; note that both the Gecko and WebKit
`matchesSelector` variants **can** handle `div span` and your
jsfiddles work as expected in the `div span` case.

What does `Sizzle(expr, null, null, [node])` do? Why it returns an array
containing the `<span>` inside your `<div>` of course.  We'll have
this in `expr`:

```
'div span:last'
```

and this in `node`:

```
<div id="d2">
    <span id="s1"></span>
</div>
```

So the `<span id="s1">` inside `node` nicely matches the selector
in `expr` and the `Sizzle()` call returns an array containing the
`<span>` and since that array has a non-zero length, the `matchesSelector`
call returns true and everything falls apart in a pile of nonsense.

The problem is that jQuery isn't interfacing with Sizzle properly in this case. Congratulations, you are the proud father of a bouncing baby bug.

Here's a (massive) jsfiddle with an inlined version of jQuery with a couple `console.log` calls to support what I'm talking about above:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TxGXv/

A few things to note:

1. You will get *sensible* results with `div span` and `div span:nth-child(1)`; both of these use the native Gecko and WebKit selector engine.
2. You will get the same *broken* results with `div span:first`, `div span:last`, and even `div span:eq(0)`; all three of these go through Sizzle.
3. The four argument version of the `Sizzle()` call that is being used not documented (see [Public API](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home)) so we don't know if jQuery or Sizzle is at fault here.

Comment: Awesome writeup. I found something list this not too long ago:  http://jsfiddle.net/KgcEW/2/ though I never took the time to figure out why!

Comment: @jamietre: Thanks, I've been poking around with this for a few days, it didn't make sense and that was bugging me. Looks like jQuery and Sizzle don't quite agree on Sizzle's interface; it is interesting that the four argument form of `Sizzle()` is not documented. Your problem could be something similar, you could try it with the quick and dirty `console.log` hacks in my fiddle, just scroll to the bottom of the JavaScript pane and you'll see what to replace.

Comment: I think my bug is less arcane - it's just a functional difference in how Sizzle treats the first option in an option group with no physical `selected` attribute (but technically selected by default). Sizzle thinks that [selected] should identify it, and querySelector doesn't. The different variations change whether sizzle is used or not for the 2nd part of the selector. This mysterious fourth argument intrigues me, though, perhaps it is akin to the fifth column...

Comment: @muistooshort - Wow, thanks for such a detailed answer, and taking the time to dig through the source. I'd been trying to follow it through myself but gave up! I'll award the much-deserved bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @James: This has been bugging me for a couple days because it didn't make any sense at all. My "grep-guess-log" code tracing technique has improved greatly from dealing with Rails. You might want to get this into jQuery bug queue, you found the bug so that glory is yours.

Comment: @muistooshort - Yeah it bugged me too when I answered the question that originally made me notice it. I'm glad it bugged you enough to spend so much time tracing the root cause :) And yeah I was planning on getting it in the bug queue probably tomorrow. I'll update the question with a link to the ticket when it's done. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Update with this

```
$('.removelink').click(function(){

$(this).parent().siblings('table').find('tr:last').remove();
```

});

Check [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd49H/8/)

Comment: I know how make it work properly, but the question is *why* it happens.